# Unable to typecast a size_t to unsigned short in an arithmetic expression in gcc

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings

I am working on a project of migration of code from 32bit to 64bit where I am facing an issue where an expression contains mix of `unsigned short` and and `size_t` variable and resultant value is `unsigned short`. 
sample code is as follows:

```
unsigned short foo = GETSOMEVALUE();
size_t bar = GETSOMEVALUE();
unsigned sort res  = foo + bar;
```

While compiling this code in gcc 64 bit I am getting warning of

> conversion to short unsigned int from "size_t" may alter its value

I added typecasting of (unsigned short) to bar in expression and compiled it and again got the warning of

> conversion to "short unsigned int" from "int" may alter its value

How can I remove above warnings keeping the type of variables unchanged?
my actual problem here is gcc is not able to typecast 64 bit type to 16 bit. It is some compiler defined issue or i am doing some thing wrong.

Comment: are you sure you want to `remove` the warnings? there are there for a reason....

Comment: @SouravGhosh i think he meant to remove the warnings "programmatically" by searching for a solution to his problem.

Comment: i want to mask those warnings which are not going to crack my code on client side hence using typecasting so that new warnings can be easily detected.

Comment: @UniCell i don't think so, especially by reading this part `while keep unchanged the type of variables`...

Comment: @SouravGhosh ...well, then you are right. Never, ever try to "mask" the warnings, only if it's made by coding.

Comment: @SouravGhosh : i am converting a huge legacy code to 64 bit where code change may not be the efficient way to do so. if you know that variable range never crosses the limit of it MAX_SIZE its ok to do typecast.

Comment: If you're fully aware of what you're doing, you could do `unsigned sort res  = (unsigned short)(foo + bar);`. Or just disable `-Wconversion` compiler flag.

Comment: @rpatle it's not `MAX_SIZE` but `USHORT_MAX`. The conversion is truncating from `size_t` to `unsigned short`, therefore losing precision. The cast in the opposite direction would be entirely safe.

Answer (score 1):

1. [`I cannot believe myself that i'm answering this`]
2. [`I'm not responsible for any consequences`]
3. [`Use this at your own risk`].

Maybe what you want is the `-Wno-conversion` switch with `gcc`.

Comment: I don't think it is enabled by default (or even by `-Wall`/`-Wextra`), so something explicitly called for this warnings. Maybe it is changed in some gcc version, though.

Comment: @keltar I am not sure [rather i'd say, i don't want to be sure]. I _love_ it when my compilar throws a warning at me. Most of the times, those `5 minutes` [resoving the warning cause] saved my hours at later stage.

Comment: @sourabh ghosh : i understand your point.. but -Wno-conversion flat is not specific to above mentioned issue but above mentioned issue has been generated by same flag so i can't remove that flag. The actual problem is gcc is not able to typecast 64bit to 16bit type.

Comment: @SouravGhosh not my point - I like warnings too, have a lot of them enabled in projects I'm working on. What I meant is something in build system explicitly enabled `-Wconversion`, - so there was a reason for that. But answer is correct, and I already +1'd it.

Comment: @keltar I'm saying the same. I was just clarifying the reason behind saying `don't want`. Hope its clear. :-)

Comment: @rpatle all i'm saying to `add`, not to `remove` this flag.